# How does one use a variable name with the same name as a package in Go?

Tags: package, go, variable-names

A common variable name for files or directories is "path".  Unfortunately that is also the name of a package in Go.  Besides, changing path as a argument name in DoIt, how do I get this code to compile?

```
package main

import (
    "path"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    DoIt("file.txt")
}

func DoIt(path string) {
    path.Join(os.TempDir(), path)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
$6g pathvar.go 
pathvar.go:4: imported and not used: path
pathvar.go:13: path.Join undefined (type string has no field or method Join)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `path string` is shadowing the imported `path`. What you can do is set imported package's alias to e.g. pathpkg by changing the line `"path"` in `import` into `pathpkg "path"`, so the start of your code goes like this

```
package main

import (
    pathpkg "path"
    "os"
)
```

Of course then you have to change the `DoIt` code into:

```
pathpkg.Join(os.TempDir(), path)
```

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer...Wish there was another way, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: You know what is kind of ironic?  The path package code doesn't have this limitation.  If you take a look at path.Split (http://golang.org/src/pkg/path/path.go?s=2665:2707#L97), you'll see it has an argument named path.  path is defined in the file, but not imported...

Comment: This limitation doesn't apply there, because there's no package `path` imported and no other `path` variable to shadow, but I can assume you already know that. ;)

Comment: Yep, I understand why, but found it kind of funny...oh well, I guess we have to deal with the limitation.

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "path"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    DoIt("file.txt")
}

// Just don't introduce a same named thing in the scope
// where you need to use the package qualifier.
func DoIt(pth string) {
    path.Join(os.TempDir(), pth)
}
```

Comment: Yep, that is the obvious way to do it.  I was just wondering if there was another way...

Comment: Of course it was not what OP meant. Your answer is totally irrelevant.