# Disambiguate package name from local var in Go

Tags: go, package

Is there a good way to disambiguate between a package name and a local variable? I'd rather not refactor the import name or variable name if I don't have to. Take for example...

```
import "path"

func foo() {
    path := "/some/path"
    // Disambiguate here
    path.Join(path, "/some/other/path")
}
```

Comment: Jeopardy! [What is namespace pollution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22903542/86967)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one use a variable name with the same name as a package in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772229/how-does-one-use-a-variable-name-with-the-same-name-as-a-package-in-go)

Comment: @kravemir This question was answered 7 years ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The local variable always overrides (shadows) the package here. Pick another variable name, or alias the package as something else:

http://play.golang.org/p/9ZaJa5Joca

or

http://play.golang.org/p/U6hvtQU8dx

See nemo's alternatives in the other answer. I think the most maintainable way is to pick a variable name that won't overlap with the package name.

Comment: I was hoping to not do either... But looks like I'll have to. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There are two additional options I can think of:

1. store `path.Join` in a variable
2. make `path` a type that implements `Join`

The first is simple. Instead of `path.Join` you store `path.Join` in a variable before declaring `path` and call it instead ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/UkLZgizzct)):

```
join := path.Join

path := "/some/path"
path = join("/some/other/path")
```

The second is a bit more complicated and I don't think you should actually do that but it is a possibility
([play](http://play.golang.org/p/VqCj1wAuoo)):

```
type Path string

func (p Path) Join(elem ...string) string {
    return path.Join(append([]string{string(p)}, elem...)...)
}

fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

path := "/some/path"

path = Path(path).Join("/some/other/path")
```

Comment: +1. clever :P I still think it's confusing to maintain code like this. cleanest way (IMO) is to pick a different variable name.

Comment: I agree. It's more of a last resort :)