# What is namespace pollution?

Tags: namespaces

What does the term 'namespace pollution' mean and why would making a method static help to prevent it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted) seems to be similar but relates specifically to JavaScript, and the answers don't define the term.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A namespace is simply the space in which names exist (seems obvious enough now).

Let's say you have two pieces of code, one to handle linked lists, the other to handle trees. Now both of these pieces of code would benefit from a `getNext()` function, to assist in traversal of the data structure.

However, if they *both* define that function with the same name, you may have a clash. What will your compiler do when you enter the following code?

```
xyzzy = getNext (xyzzy);
```

In other words, which `getNext()` do you actually want to use? There are numerous ways to solve this, such as with object-oriented code, where you would use:

```
xyzzy = xyzzy.getNext();
```

and that would auto-magically select the correct one by virtue of the fact you've specified the type via the variable `xyzzy` itself.

But, even with mostly-OO code, there may be situations where you have a conflict, and that's where namespaces enter the picture. They allow you to place the names into their own area so as to distinguish them.

C++, as one example, places all its standard library stuff into the `std` namespace. If, for some reason, you need an `fopen()` or `rand()` function that works differently from the one in the library, you can place it in your *own* namespace to keep them separate.

Now that describes namespace *clashes.* Technically, namespace *pollution* is simply leaving your symbols in a namespace where they shouldn't really be. This doesn't necessarily lead to clashes but it makes it more likely.

---

The reason why making a method static (in C-like languages) has to do with the names being made available to the world outside the given translation unit (when linking, for example). With the code:

```
int get42 (void) { return 42; }
int main (void) { return get42(); }
```

*both* of those functions are made available to the linker.

Unless you have a need to call `get42()` from somewhere else, making it static:

```
static int get42 (void) { return 42; }
int main (void) { return get42(); }
```

will prevent it from polluting the namespace maintained by the linker – in C, applying the `static` qualifier to a file-level object or function gives it *internal* linkage.

It's similar to the C++ namespaces in that you can have a `static int get42()` in four hundred *different* source files and they won't interfere with each other.

Comment: Ok so it just means untidy namespaces. Any idea how making a method static avoids namespace pollution as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/169382/707103 ?

Comment: @lockstock: static non-class functions are not visible outside of the translation unit, which prevents pollution of the "linking" namespace.  If two translation units have a static object, they won't conflict when you link them together. Nowadays, this is better handled with anonymous namespaces, which can be used to similar effect.

Answer (score 4):

Namespace pollution is a lot like pollution in general. It means that something is misplaced. In programming that means that code that should really live in separate namespaces is added to a common namespace (in some cases the global namespace). This can happen with both static and non static code, so I don't really see a scenario where static helps prevent namespace pollution.

Basically, namespaces' main function is to categorize code, and both static and non static code must be defined in a namespace somewhere.

Comment: Ok fair enough I wasn't taking the term literally. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/169382/707103