# Send The Portion Of The Server ID Next To It

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I use the test command, I'd like to access the value that's being stored in the dictionary:

[image]

However, I keep getting this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '714235745140736080'
```

Here is my code:

```
def test1(client, message):
    with open('test.json', "r") as f:
        test = json.load(f)
    return (test[str(message.guild.id)])



@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
        test = json.load(f)
        test1 = (test[str(ctx.guild.id)])

        await ctx.send(f"{test1}")
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's nothing in your code that suggests that you've actually *created* an entry with the guild ID as a key and written it to the file. After you've edited in all the necessary code, it'll be easier to narrow down what the issue is. There also seems to be some namespace pollution with regards to `test1` - you have defined a function with the name, and in your command you also have a variable called `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

JSON files work similarly to dictionaries in Python. When you create a dictionary with keys and values, you're able to save it to the `.json`. These values are then able to be accessed when loading the file in, exactly as you would access a dictionary normally:

```py
# Creating a dictionary with some arbitrary values
>>> data = {"foo": "bar", "key": "value"}

# Opening a file and writing to it
>>> with open("db.json", "w+") as fp:
...     json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4) # Kwargs for beautification

# Loading in data from a file
>>> with open("db.json", "r") as fp:
...     data = json.load(fp)

# Accessing the values
>>> data["foo"]
'bar'
>>> data["key"]
'value'
```

With that out of the way, we can move onto your problem.

---

First off, I'd recommend choosing more sensible names for functions and variables. This will help to avoid [namespace pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903542/what-is-namespace-pollution).

Here's an example of some working code with better names:

```py
# Adding a default paramter type will mean that you won't need to convert throughout the function
def get_data(guild_id: str):
    with open("guilds.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data[guild_id]

@client.command()
async def cmd(ctx):
    value = get_data(ctx.guild.id)
    await ctx.send(f"{value}")
```

One thing to note was that you weren't actually making use of the function you defined. You just rewrote its code later on in the script. The point of a function is to prevent you from repeating code like this. You want to *call* the function (e.g. `my_func()`) in order to do something with it.

---

I'm guessing you already have a method of writing/updating values to the file. If not, then there should be enough information in this answer to do so.

You'll get a `KeyError` when you try to access a key in a dictionary that doesn't exist. For this reason, I'd maybe recommend looking into an `on_guild_join()` event as to update the file when the bot joins a new guild.

I believe what caused the error in your case was trying to access the value of a key whose type was actually `str` and not an `int` - they are completely different. Consider the following:

```py
>>> data = {"123": "value"}
>>> data[123] # This will throw a KeyError

>>> data["123"] # This will return the value
'value'
```

---

**References:**

- [Dictionary exercises](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) - Might be worth taking a look into so then you're comfortable with how they work.
- [Namespace pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903542/what-is-namespace-pollution)
- [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - Python's styling guide. I'd recommend reading through this, or at least skimming through the contents on anything you might be unsure of.
- [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)
- [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)
- [`Context.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild)
- [`Guild.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.id)
- [`on_guild_join()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_join)