# Using classes, functions or other objects from an installed package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I successfully installed this package using pip:

```
pip install functional-dependencies
```

Output:

```
Collecting functional-dependencies
  Downloading functional_dependencies-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Installing collected packages: functional-dependencies
Successfully installed functional-dependencies-1.3.0
```

which should provide tools for [functional dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) (FDs).

However, trying to get FDs using [the commands as per the documentation](https://oer.gitlab.io/cs/functional-dependencies/) results in an error:

```
Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> fd1 = FD("CustomerID", "DateOfBirth")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'FD' is not defined
```

How can I access the classes, functions and objects from the installed package?

Comment: The pypi page of the package you are using links to an [example notebook](https://mybinder.org/v2/gl/oer%2Fcs%2Ffunctional-dependencies/HEAD?filepath=notebooks%2FCodd-3NF-ex.ipynb). Note that this package is not about finding FDs but rather normalizing a schema. You can instead try looking at [FDTool](https://github.com/USEPA/FDTool) (not maintained since 3 years or so) although I'd advice you to simply find the FDs as per the duplicates of your previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is a *very* basic question, just because the official [documentation](https://oer.gitlab.io/cs/functional-dependencies/) does not include full working examples, I will provide an answer here.

You have already installed the module [functional-dependencies](https://pypi.org/project/functional-dependencies/). To use it, you'll need to know the module name to use to import. This is written in the first line of the introduction:

> The module [functional_dependencies](https://gitlab.com/oer/cs/functional-dependencies/-/blob/master/functional_dependencies/functional_dependencies.py) defines the classes [FD](https://oer.gitlab.io/cs/functional-dependencies/#functional_dependencies.FD), [FDSet](https://oer.gitlab.io/cs/functional-dependencies/#functional_dependencies.FDSet), and [RelSchema](https://oer.gitlab.io/cs/functional-dependencies/#functional_dependencies.RelSchema) to represent a single functional dependency (FD), a set of FDs, and a relation schema, respectively.

So, you'll start by doing:

```py
import functional_dependencies
```

or

```py
from functional_dependencies import *
```

The latter is generally not recommended because of [namespace pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903542/what-is-namespace-pollution), but since you probably want to copy-paste examples from the documentation, this will be easier.

Now you can do:

```py
from functional_dependencies import *

fd1 = FD("CustomerID", "DateOfBirth")
fd1.isrminimal()
```

Otherwise you would have to include the module name to access the classes:

```py
import functional_dependencies

fd1 = functional_dependencies.FD("CustomerID", "DateOfBirth")
fd1.isrminimal()
```

Now, for the rest of your journey, reading the documentation should be helpful. Other tricks that might be useful is typing `help(functional_dependencies)` in the Python interpreter. It will print all functions and classes that are defined in the module, including the available documentation. You can also do this on an object: `help(fd1)` would print help about the object. You can also execute `dir(fd1)` to see which attributes the object has, which includes all its methods.